# How can I merge two geometry columns of different tables to a single column in another table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I have many tables with geometry attribute which is saved in Postgis database. These tables are basically from more than one shapefiles which is stored in Postgis using geotools.

Now I want a common table to handle all the `geom` attributes in the table, as shown in the below example

For eg:

[image]

Is there a way to do this using PostGIS? Initially the Table `geom_all` with `geom` column contains NULL value. I tried updating the values using JOINS with the below query example.

```
 UPDATE Geom_all g SET geom = (SELECT geom FROM Table-1 t WHERE g.id = t.id);
```

But this overrides with every new value i update in the `geom` column and also the sub query should return only 1 row, which in my case is not. I am not sure whether I can achieve this task using JOINS, it would be helpful to know if there is any other way to solve this.

**NOTE:** All the geom column contains `geometry_type` as *MULTIPOLYGON* and `ST_SRID` as *4326*.

Comment: Can you union all the rows together from tables 1, 2 etc. ? You migt want a new column to give all the rows a unique ID

Comment: Yes Dave I tried doing a ST_union (geom), but this removes the ID info. How do i handle this? however I need the geom specific ID info to map other attributes based on the ID later.

Comment: Answer below was what I was refering to. ST_Union is trying to 'join' the geometries, where you just want to union the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to merge the rows from multiple tables. You don't need to alter the geometry

```
Create table geom_all as
Select ID, geom from table1
UNION
select ID, geom from table2
UNION 
select ID, geom from table 3;
```

or if the table already exists:

```
Insert into geom_all (select ID, geom from table1);
```

Comment: I didnt expect it to be so straight forward, thank you @JGH :)